# how to scale svg based on viewport

Tags: html, css, svg, scale

So I began with a basic SVG circle, but I want it to be able to scale based on the viewport size.

```
<svg height="100" width="100">  <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="15" fill="black"></circle>  </svg>
```

I know that with CSS I can take this sample div:

```
<div class="test_div"></div>
```

and use this CSS:

```
.test_div {height:5vh; width: 5vh;}
```

to effectively make test_div keep the same proportions as the viewport height changes. Is there a way to replace the SVG attribute values with some sort of scale-able size unit? i.e.

```
<circle cx="10vh" cy="10vh" r="5vh" fill="black"></circle>
```

I've never used StackOverflow before so help me out here if I was too vague -- thanks!

Comment: Good question. +1. I have always wondered how to scale up svg graphics (whatever it might be) according to the browser size. Yet to discover a working one for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using pixel values, use percentage values for the circle size based on the ATSC HD standard 16:9 aspect ratio. Pixels for measurements are outdated.